# errors when creating for loops for KDE in GME

Tags: kernel-density, gme

I am trying to create kernel density estimates for bird territories over a number of years. So I have all of the x,y coordinates that mark the locations of each bird in my spreadsheet, and columns for Year and Bird ID. I want to create a kernel density estimate for each bird's territory each year - some birds have returned in multiple years and established territories, so I need a KDE for each bird, each year. I can get it to work doing it one at a time, but that would be time consuming and unpleasant with 100's of unique combinations of Bird ID and Year to go through, so I have been trying to batch automate it and am running into trouble.

**This is what I put in the command text on the GME GUI:**

```
inpath <- ”V:\shapefiles\” 
outpath <- ”V:\shapefiles\” 
for (i in 1:44) 
   { for (j in 2009:2015) 
       { kde(in=paste(inpath, ”Master6.shp”), 
            out=paste(outpath, ”kde an”, i, ” m”, j, ”.img”), 
            bandwidth="SCV", 
            cellsize=0.000168, 
            where=paste(”Bird ID=”, i, ” ANDYear=”, j)); 
        }; 
    };
```

**This is the output and error I get:**

```
inpath <- "V:\shapefiles\" 
outpath <- "V:\shapefiles\" 
for (i in 1:44);   
kde(in=paste(inpath, "Master6.shp"), 
out=paste(outpath, "kde an", i, " m", 2009, ".img"), 
bandwidth="SCV", cellsize=0.000168, 
where=paste("Bird ID=", i, " ANDYear=",   2009));
```

> Error: The default input/output working folders have not been
>   specified, therefore not enough information has been supplied to open
>   the specified data source
>
> Error: Could not open input point data source.

I'm new to GME.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that need to be cleaned up in your code example. I think the quotes may clean up the input source error you are receiving, if not, changing from a mapped drive to UNC might.

1. You need a space between AND & Year in your last line.
2. Check your quotations. You may need to either find and replace or manually change them up. They're different in your code vs the [Example Code from GME](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/strategiccommands.htm)
3. Bandwidth likely needs an integer, not a string.
4. Make sure your V: Drive/folder are accessible. If this is a network drive you may want to use the UNC path instead of a mapped drive.

   Example code from GME (site referenced above):

> ```
> inpath <- "C:\data\"
> outpath <- "C:\output\"
> for (i in 1001:1010) {
>  for (j in 1:12) {
> kde(in=paste(inpath, "telemetry.shp"), 
> out=paste(outpath, "kde_an", i, "_m", j, ".img"), bandwidth=1000,
> cellsize=r.eval((250000-120000)/2000), where=paste("ANIMALID=", i, "
>      AND MONTH=", j));
> };
>  };
> ```

Versus your code:

```
inpath <- ”V:\shapefiles\” 
outpath <- ”V:\shapefiles\” 
for (i in 1:44) 
   { for (j in 2009:2015) 
       { kde(in=paste(inpath, ”Master6.shp”), 
            out=paste(outpath, ”kde an”, i, ” m”, j, ”.img”), 
            bandwidth="SCV", 
            cellsize=0.000168, 
            where=paste(”Bird ID=”, i, ” ANDYear=”, j)); 
        }; 
    };
```